How to perform spark stream-stream inner join with aggregation?
I'm trying to perform a inner join between two streaming dataframes, where one of the dataframes has an aggregation performed on it. The resulting dataframe always ends up being empty. Testing with static versions of the same dataframes and using the same join produces the expected result.
To be specific, I am using databricks autoloader to load in files from cloud storage using structured streaming. From this stream I create another streaming dataframe, apply some transformations and a groupBy, and then join this streaming dataframe back to the original one (thus the stream-stream join).
I've applied a watermark to the aggregated dataframe as is required, but according to the documentation watermarking is optional for an inner join between two streams.
Some example code:
df = (spark.readStream
  .format("cloudFiles") 
  .option("cloudFiles.format", "csv")
  .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .schema(schema)
  .load(path)
)

second_df = df.filter(df["name"].startswith("abc") # creating second streaming dataframe
second_df = second_df.withColumn("write_timestamp", current_timestamp()) # creating timestamp column
second_df = second_df.withWatermark("write_timestamp", "5 minutes") \
     .groupBy("name", "item", "type", "write_timestamp") \
     .agg(collect_list("value").alias("values")) # set watermark and aggregate

merged_df = df.join(second_df, on = (df.item == second_df.item), how = "inner")

(merged_df.writeStream
  .outputMode("append") 
  .option("checkpointLocation",  checkpoint_path) 
  .option("mergeSchema", "true") 
  .trigger(availableNow=True) 
  .toTable(tablename))

Should I be including a watermark on the non-aggregated streaming dataframe as well? Does the join condition need to include a watermark range condition? I am not sure why the result of this join could be empty.
